# Creating a D3 Line Graph with Points using 2 Level Nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nested

For the life of me, I can't seem to find a clear answer on how to handle this. Granted, I'm still pretty new to javascript and D3, but I can't find any good examples.

I am currently trying to create a D3 multi-line graph with points. I've had some pretty good success with a flat JSON file, but when my JSON data was modified to add an additional layer of nesting, I really began to struggle.

My JSON data file now looks something like this:

```
{
    "Model": "Model A", 
    "Data": [
        {
            "Metric": "Metric 1", 
            "Data": [
                    {"Date":"2017-2-25", "Value": "34"}, 
                    {"Date":"2017-2-26", "Value": "52"},
                    {"Date":"2017-2-27", "Value": "47"},
                    {"Date":"2017-2-28", "Value": "50"}
             ]
        }, 
        {
            "Metric": "Metric 2", 
            "Data": [
                    {"Date":"2017-2-25", "Value": "22"}, 
                    {"Date":"2017-2-26", "Value": "27"},
                    {"Date":"2017-2-27", "Value": "25"},
                    {"Date":"2017-2-28", "Value": "21"}
             ]
        }, 
        {
            "Metric": "Metric 3", 
            "Data": [
                    {"Date":"2017-2-25", "Value": "27"}, 
                    {"Date":"2017-2-26", "Value": "28"},
                    {"Date":"2017-2-27", "Value": "25"},
                    {"Date":"2017-2-28", "Value": "22"}
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This extra nested layer was added so I could filter by model and metric.

Assuming I do not have multiple "Models" in my JSON file (so taking the JSON exactly as it is from the above snippet). How do I effectively plot `Value` and `Date` per metric (multi-line chart)? If anyone could point me to some working examples as well, that would be an incredible help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data structure, a possible solution is binding the data (specifically the outer `Data` array) to groups:

```
var groups = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data.Data)
    .enter()
    .append("g");
```

And using each inner `Data` array as the data to each line:

```
var lines = groups.append("path")
    .attr("d", d => lineGen(d.Data))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", (d, i) => colors(i));
```

Here is a demo using your data object:

```js
var data = {
    "Model": "Model A",
    "Data": [{
        "Metric": "Metric 1",
        "Data": [{
            "Date": "2017-2-25",
            "Value": "34"
        }, {
            "Date": "2017-2-26",
            "Value": "52"
        }, {
            "Date": "2017-2-27",
            "Value": "47"
        }, {
            "Date": "2017-2-28",
            "Value": "50"
        }]
    }, {
        "Metric": "Metric 2",
        "Data": [{
            "Date": "2017-2-25",
            "Value": "22"
        }, {
            "Date": "2017-2-26",
            "Value": "27"
        }, {
            "Date": "2017-2-27",
            "Value": "25"
        }, {
            "Date": "2017-2-28",
            "Value": "21"
        }]
    }, {
        "Metric": "Metric 3",
        "Data": [{
            "Date": "2017-2-25",
            "Value": "27"
        }, {
            "Date": "2017-2-26",
            "Value": "28"
        }, {
            "Date": "2017-2-27",
            "Value": "25"
        }, {
            "Date": "2017-2-28",
            "Value": "22"
        }]
    }]
};

var width = 500,
    height = 300;

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .range([30, width - 20])
    .domain(d3.extent(data.Data[0].Data, d => parse(d.Date)));

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height - 20, 20])
    .domain([0, 60]);

var lineGen = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(parse(d.Date)))
    .y(d => yScale(d.Value));

var groups = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data.Data)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

var lines = groups.append("path")
    .attr("d", d => lineGen(d.Data))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", (d, i) => colors(i));

var gX = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - 20) + ")").call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

var gY = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,0)").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you so much for the explanation! Very helpful. Quick question-- the arrow function you have in your code is throwing an error for me. What can I replace that with for the code to still work? Something like function(d) ...?

Comment: Replace it by `.attr("d", function (d){ return lineGen(d.Data)})`.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up having to revert back to version 3 of the d3 library and use the modification you suggested. My browser was having issues supporting v4 and the arrow function.  After that, I got the graph to render.

Comment: The only browser I know doesn't support arrow functions is IE. Are you using IE?

Comment: It was choking in Chrome, which was surprising and unexpected. Admittedly, was an older version (43). Everything seemed to work fine in Firefox. 

Obviously, more updated browser versions won't have this problem.

Comment: Here is a fiddle for my updated code. I've got a few more questions to ask, but you definitely answered my main question! 

https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/1uszmp73/2/